# Why unknown type name 'Complejo'?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a simple example.

**EXAMPLE 1**
If for example I declare this code (with class Complejo in same file):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Complejo com(1,1);

  cout << com << endl;

}


class Complejo
{
private:
  double real;
  double imaginario;
public:
  //Complejo();
  Complejo(double real, double imaginario)
  {
    real = 1;
    imaginario = 2;
  }
  double getReal() { return real; }
  double getImaginario() { return imaginario; }
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, Complejo& comp)
{
  stream << comp.getReal() << " + " << comp.getReal()<< endl;
  return stream;
}
```

My compiler says me:

> sobrecarga_ostream.cpp:15:3: error: unknown type name 'Complejo'

**EXAMPLE 2**
But If I create sobrecarga_ostream.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Complejo.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
  Complejo com(1,1);


  cout << com << endl;

}
```

and Complejo.h:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Complejo
{
private:
  double real;
  double imaginario;
public:
  //Complejo();
  Complejo(double real, double imaginario)
  {
    real = 1;
    imaginario = 2;
  }
  double getReal() { return real; }
  double getImaginario() { return imaginario; }
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, Complejo& comp)
{
  stream << comp.getReal() << " + " << comp.getReal()<< endl;
  return stream;
}
```

Then, it works well.

Why does not "main + class" work in the same file and if I separate files then works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the type before it is declared. If you rearrange your first example to

```
using namespace std;

class Complejo {
    //...
};

int main()
{
  Complejo com(1,1);

  cout << com << endl;

}
```

It will complie. Note that `#include` does nothing more than including the contents of the header into the source file. So your example 2 is more or less the same as the above.

PS: Please read [why is using namespace std considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 2):

> Why does not "main + class" work in the same file

Because when the compiler sees the line

```
Complejo com(1,1);
```

in your `main` functions, it needs to have seen the definition of type `Complejo` beforehand. There is no way around it - whether you put it into a header file and include that or whether you cut and paste the class definition from below the `main` function on top of it doesn't matter, both approaches work.

Comment: Wow men! I don´t know how I haven´t thought this! =) Thank you!